# what values should i pass to the normalization function in iris recognition?

Tags: matlab, normalization, iris-recognition

i've been working on implementation for iris recognition system in Matlab ,
on Normalization i used this function

```
[polar_array, polar_noise] = normaliseiris(image, x_iris, y_iris, r_iris,x_pupil, y_pupil, r_pupil, eyeimage_filename, radpixels, angulardiv);
```

i passed x, y and radius coordinates for both circles (iris and pupil) to x_iris, y_iris, r_iris,x_pupil, y_pupil, r_pupil

but i'm stuck at these two variables (radpixels, angulardiv) !!
couldn't figure out what values should i pass ?!
i saw someone said he/she passed 32 , 240 respectively but it didn't work with me !
Can anyone tell me what values should i pass ? or at least an explanation ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it clearly said in the comments?

```
% radpixels             - radial resolution, defines vertical dimension of
%                         normalised representation
% angulardiv            - angular resolution, defines horizontal dimension
%                         of normalised representation
```

([Source](http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~cseri/edu/Biometrika/Iris/normaliseiris.m))

Note: "32, 240" can be useful values... but how shall we know what's wrong with your parametrization without more details? You should think about how much radpixels and angulardiv are useful for your application.

Comment: Sorry i was stupid lol . I just needed to pass the size of the matrix to both radpixels, angulardiv . Thank you anw !!:)

Comment: @91em Can you tell me how can I get both radpixels, angulardiv using matlab?